# What kind of regular expression matches these inputs?

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to parse data from a measurement machine. It outputs unstructured data of the following shape (tab separated):

```
# control.dat
X001  A3      100.0   20.0    40.0
      A5      124.0   
      I3      125.0 
X002  C3      200.054 20.494  45.0
      C5      122.0
      K3      122.01
```

Is it advisable to use a regular expression to find the lines starting with `X0...` and if so how to do this? Using the resulting parsed data, I'd like to populate a Python dictionary in the following form (such that it can be easily converted to JSON if needed):

```
{ "PARSED" : [
    {
        "PARAM_1" : 100.0,
        "PARAM_2" : 20.0,
        "PARAM_3" : 40.0
    },
    {
        "PARAM_1" : 200.054,
        "PARAM_2" : 20.494
        "PARAM_3" : 45.0
    }
]}
```

Currently I'm using something along the lines of:

```
with("control.dat") as controls_data:
    controls = []
    for row in controls_data.split("\r\n"):
        #                   X          A3        100.0         20.0        40.0 
        tmp = re.findall(r"^X \d* \s* \D\d* \s* \d*\.\d* \s* \d*\.\d* \s* \d*.\d* \s*$", row)
        if len(tmp) > 0:
            controls.append(tmp[0])
    return controls_ra
```

Is it really needed to use a forloop to run over all entries and collect those rows which match the pattern in a separate list? Is there a regular expression that can be applied to the list of lines at once?

Any suggestion should be compatible with Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to load all the lines as a string with for example

```
file = open('control.dat',mode='r')
s = file.read()
```

And then use `groupdict()` and named capture groups

```
^X0\d+\s+\w+\s*(?P<PARAM_1>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+(?P<PARAM_2>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+(?P<PARAM_3>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `X0\d+\s+\w+\s*` Match `X0` 1+ and 1+ word chars *(you could make it more specific using `[A-Z]\d+`)*
- `(?P<PARAM_1>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+` Named group `PARAM_1` matching 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `(?P<PARAM_2>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+` Named group `PARAM_2` matching 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `(?P<PARAM_3>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` Named group `PARAM_3` matching 1+ digits with an optional decimal part

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IlF8sb/1) | [Python 2 demo](https://ideone.com/gKqcOv)

```
s = ("X001  A3      100.0   20.0    40.0\n"
            "      A5      124.0   \n"
            "      I3      125.0 \n"
            "X002  C3      200.054 20.494  45.0\n"
            "      C5      122.0\n"
            "      K3      122.01\n"
            "        \n")

pattern = r"^X0\d+\s+\w+\s*(?P<PARAM_1>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+(?P<PARAM_2>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+(?P<PARAM_3>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)"
r = re.compile(r"^X0\d+\s+\w+\s*(?P<PARAM_1>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+(?P<PARAM_2>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+(?P<PARAM_3>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)", re.MULTILINE)
dict = {'PARSED': [m.groupdict() for m in r.finditer(s)]}

print(dict)
```

Output

```
{'PARSED': [{'PARAM_1': '100.0', 'PARAM_2': '20.0', 'PARAM_3': '40.0'}, {'PARAM_1': '200.054', 'PARAM_2': '20.494', 'PARAM_3': '45.0'}]}
```

---

If you want to loop per line, you can use re.match and check `if tmp:` has a result as you don't have to use split, as the row already has the data for the current row.

Example

```
with open("control.dat", "r") as controls_data:
    controls = []
    dict = {}
    dict.setdefault('PARSED', [])
    for row in controls_data:
        tmp = re.match(r"^X0\d+\s+\w+\s*(?P<PARAM_1>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+(?P<PARAM_2>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+(?P<PARAM_3>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)", row)
        if tmp:
            dict['PARSED'].append(tmp.groupdict())
    print(dict)
```

Output

```
{'PARSED': [{'PARAM_1': '100.0', 'PARAM_2': '20.0', 'PARAM_3': '40.0'}, {'PARAM_1': '200.054', 'PARAM_2': '20.494', 'PARAM_3': '45.0'}]}
```